# Unexpected Full GC (Ergonomic)

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm running application that consists of 3 stages: load initial data, update it using POST http requests, serve it using GET requests.
After all data is set up (initial load + POST updates) I'm calling System.gc() and I see

```
[Full GC (System.gc()) 2051102K->1082623K(3298304K), 13.3521960 secs]
```

So I expect that I need about 1000M for old gen and run my app with such setup (at 4G RAM docker container):

```
java -XX:MaxNewSize=2550m -XX:NewSize=2550m -Xms3750m -Xmx3750m -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGC -cp my.jar my.My
```

So I expect that from 3750M of heap 2550M will be used for new space to serve GET requests and 1200M will be for old gen.
During the work of my application I have

```
[Full GC (Ergonomics) 2632447K->1086729K(3298304K), 2.3360398 secs]
```

So it looks very strange for me that full GC is triggered. My understanding is that because GET requests don't add any long-living data it should be just Minor GC when new generation is full. So I don't understand

1) Why it is running Full GC (Ergonomics) - does it want to change generation layout?

2) Why it is running when only 2632447K of 3298304K are occupied?

Comment: Just profile it.

Comment: instead of pasting logs in comments you should update your question

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

- GET/POST has nothing to do with it, the logic that you implemented for GET/POST is what matters... e.g. the GET method might have a memory leak...
- Growing memory doesn't necessarily reduce GC (it doesn’t work in linearly)
- GC usually freezes for ~1 sec per live GB, so the fact that you're having 13 secs freeze for 1 GB worths checking
- The next step should be [enabling GC log](https://dzone.com/articles/enabling-and-analysing-the-garbage-collection-log) and analyzing it to have a better understanding of the issue

Comment: Thanks, I've added log here: https://pastebin.com/b3ggH6wX (Ergonomic GC is the last line). So after System.gc() we have {[PSYoungGen: 1760K->0K(2086912K)] [ParOldGen: 1097657K->1080797K(1228800K)] 1099417K->1080797K(3315712K), [Metaspace: 18466K->18466K(1067008K)], 4.5801664 secs]}, after Ergonomics GC  [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 1576960K->0K(2086912K)] [ParOldGen: 1080797K->1080725K(1228800K)] 2657757K->1080725K(3315712K), [Metaspace: 18568K->18568K(1067008K)], 1.4782103 secs]. So size of YoungGen and OldGen are not changed, what is done in Ergonomics GC in this case?

Comment: @dbf don't try to read it by yourself, use a log-analyzer, there are plenty of them!

Comment: You're setting the min and max size of new generation to be the same thing`-XX:MaxNewSize=2550m -XX:NewSize=2550m`. remove the max and try again!

Comment: alfasin, thanks for suggestion. I've tried to run without MaxNewSize and still have 2017-09-03T23:13:51.282+0300: 217.526: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 1571840K->0K(2099712K)] [ParOldGen: 1081163K->1080718K(1228800K)] 2653003K->1080718K(3328512K), [Metaspace: 18569K->18569K(1067008K)], 1.4186698 secs] [Times: user=5.38 sys=0.02, real=1.42 secs]

Comment: There's a big difference between 1.4 secs and 13 secs. Try to increase the min to 3GB

Comment: 1.4 sec is GC Ergonomic, while 13 secs was a full gc that I called using System.gc() that includes old gen cleanup also, as I understand. I've tried with 3GB and there is: 2017-09-03T23:24:14.040+0300: 180.429: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 1957888K->409185K(2543616K)] [ParOldGen: 671537K->671537K(694272K)] 2629425K->1080723K(3237888K), [Metaspace: 18539K->18539K(1067008K)], 1.6589249 secs] [Times: user=5.96 sys=0.00, real=1.66 secs]

Comment: Read: https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/the-unspoken-the-why-of-gc-ergonomics pay attention to the part he's discussing pause time and it's trade-off